# Cannot use GraphQLSchema from another module or realm

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-js

I am building a serverless backend using `type-graphql` and `apollo-server-lambda`, but after around third request to graphql endpoint I get an error

```
Error: Cannot use GraphQLSchema "[object GraphQLSchema]" from another module or realm.

Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules
directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the dependencies of other
relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure only one version is installed.
```

I have already downgraded `type-graphql` because version `1.0.0` requires `graphql@^15.3.0` while some other dependencies require `graphql <= 14`

Here are my dependencies

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/graphql": "14.5.0",
    "apollo-server-lambda": "^2.17.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.750.0",
    "graphql": "^14.7.0",
    "pg": "^8.3.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "type-graphql": "^0.17.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.62",
    "@types/aws-sdk": "^2.7.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.13",
    "@types/node": "^14.10.0",
    "apollo-server-testing": "^2.17.0",
    "serverless": "^2.0.0",
    "serverless-offline": "^6.7.0",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.3.4",
    "ts-jest": "^26.3.0",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "graphql": "^14.7.0",
  },
```

`npm ls graphql` result

```
dives-backend@1.0.0
├─┬ @types/graphql@14.5.0
│ └── graphql@14.7.0  deduped
└── graphql@14.7.0
```

and `index.ts`

```js
import "reflect-metadata"
import { buildSchemaSync } from "type-graphql"
import { HelloResolver } from "./src/resolvers/example"

const schema = buildSchemaSync({
    resolvers: [HelloResolver],
    validate: false,
})

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    playground: { endpoint: "/dev/graphql" },
})

export const handler = server.createHandler({
        cors: {
            origin: true,
            credentials: true,
        },
    })
```

Comment: Doesn't `apollo-server-lambda` somehow depend on a `graphql` version as well?

Comment: Yes it does, `apollo-server-core@2.17.0` requires `"graphql": "^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0"` as a peerDependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. I upgraded both `apollo-server-lambda` to `3.0.0-alpha.3` and reverted `type-graphql` back to `^1.0.0`. I also upgraded the `resolution` to `"graphql": "15.3.0"`

also an important step when using type-graphql with lambda is to override the global object (name `schema` matters) - [reference issue](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/96)

```js
if (!global.schema) {
  global.schema = buildSchemaSync({
    resolvers: [UserResolver],
    validate: false,
  });
}
const schema = global.schema;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found an advice in [typegraphql FAQ](https://typegraphql.com/docs/faq.html).
`npm dedupe` solved it for me.